# Qt odd layout arrangement

Tags: qt, qlayout, qgridlayout

I got the following arrangement (original [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3306414/teste.png)):

[image: test_image]

Five unconvencional unsual sized buttons (w:400, h:300) and they are arranged int the following way: four square mode (two on top and two at buttom), closely tight together, and a fifth button in the center, overlaping the instersection of the other four buttons. I would like to know if is there any layout (gridlayout, form layout, etc) that I can use to keep this arrangement when I expand, maximize and/or minimize the window? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use QGridLayout, with size 4x4. Then make each button use 2x2 grid layout cells, which you can use by using the right [`QGridLayout::addWidget()` overload](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2). There give `columnSpan` and `rowSpan` of 2.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(Sounds like a homework question.)

My first approach was to just parent a second widget to the first widget after setting a grid layout.  Then you have to get the second widget to resize with the first.  I've done that in the past with [pop up dialogs in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24394628/999943).

@hyde's solution is much more elegant for the problem.  I placed everything on the heap, but for such a simple application, everything could be put on the stack instead (`QWidget * w = new QWidget();` => `QWidget w;`).

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QList>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget * w = new QWidget();

    QGridLayout * grid = new QGridLayout();

    QList <QPushButton *> buttons;
    for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++)
    {
        buttons.append(new QPushButton("Button "+ QString::number(i+1)));
        buttons.last()->setFixedSize(400, 300);
    }

    grid->addWidget(buttons.at(0),0,0,2,2);// upper left
    grid->addWidget(buttons.at(1),0,2,2,2);// upper right
    grid->addWidget(buttons.at(2),2,0,2,2);// lower left
    grid->addWidget(buttons.at(3),2,2,2,2);// lower right
    grid->addWidget(buttons.at(4),1,1,2,2);// centered

    w->setLayout(grid);

    w->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

If you want the grid elements to stay centered and not have gaps when you adjust the size of the grid, make sure you add a buffer row/col around the outside, and set the stretch value for them.  Like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21370406/999943).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try it ena let you know.